# Method added using SetRenderMethodDelegate doesn't get called

Tags: c#, methods, delegates, postback, page-lifecycle

I'm setting the render method for Page:

```
    Page.SetRenderMethodDelegate(new RenderMethod(RenderCustom));
```

And this is the method:

```
    private void RenderCustom(HtmlTextWriter output, Control container)
    {
        output.Write("<br/><br/><b>TEST</b><br/><br/>");
    }
```

It never gets called.

The page is derived from `Page` and does not implement a 'Render()' method.

I tried adding a `override void Render()` method, overriding the Page one, to see if that got called and it did. I'm aware that all `Render()` methods have to call `base.Render()` but there is none, so the call gets passed to `Page`.

But my `RenderCustom` method stays untouched.

`Page.PreRender += new EventHandler(page_PreRender);` works fine, `page_preRender(object sender, EventArgs e)` is called.

But `RenderCustom` isn't!

Why?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it's supposed to work with Page. From googling around it seems like this method only works with custom controls.
On a Page you should just put:

```
<%@ Page AutoEventWireup="true" %>
```

On it, and the Page Events get called automatically.

- Page_Init
- Page_Load
- Page_PreRender
- etc. (look up on "ASP.NET Page Lifecycle")